# Flickering when scrollTop executed?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

When I this code is executed :

```
window.scrollTop(0,$(this).offset().top));
```

I getting flicker in the page ( white page show up the the content show up again)

I tried to use another way like this

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 'slow');
```

and this white page I mean flickering still show up.

Any suggestion might be help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `$.mobile.silentScroll()`?

From [the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html): "$.mobile.silentScroll() -  Scroll to a particular Y position without triggering scroll event listeners."

```
//scroll to Y 100px
$.mobile.silentScroll(100);
```

Comment: This solve the problem but , I need to scroll with animation, Any idea?